# Linq SelectMany query not working

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have the following database tables where the relationship between Topic and Comment is 1:N

```
Category
id
name

Topic
id
title
category_id

Comment
id
details
topic_id
deleted (boolean)
```

I want a query to count total comments in each category. I have the following LINQ query but it doesn't work:

```
@foreach (var cat in Model.AllPermissionSets.Keys)

{
   var commentCount = cat.Topics.Where(c => c.Comments.deleted != 0).SelectMany(x => x.Comments).Count();

   @* some other stuff *@
}
```

In Visual studio I get error `IList<Comment> doesn not contain a definition for deleted...`

What's the correct syntax to do the above?

Comment: FWIW, this has nothing to do with the SelectMany. The problem is in your Where clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Comments` is a collection type property on each `Topic` instance. This collection does not have a `deleted` property. But each item in the collection(*a single instance of `Comment`*) has it.

```
var commentCount = cat.Topics.Where(c => c.Comments.Any(s=>!s.deleted))
                             .SelectMany(x => x.Comments).Count();
```

This will give you the count of non deleted comments from all the posts of the category.

The first part, `cat.Topics.Where(c => c.Comments.Any(s=>!s.deleted))` will give you a filtered list of `Topic` collection which has at least one non deleted comment. In the second part, you are selecting the `Comments` of All those posts and doing a Count.

*Copied from **Ivan Stoev**'s comment below*.

The below query will also produce the same result, but more clean.

```
var commentCount =cat.Topics.SelectMany(t => t.Comments.Where(c => !c.Deleted)).Count();
```

Comment: Isn't it better in this specific case to just have a `Where` inside the `SelectMany`

Comment: How is it better ?

Comment: To avoid `EXISTS` subquery (the `Any` part). I mean, something like `cat.Topics.SelectMany(t => t.Comments.Where(c => !c.Deleted)).Count()`

Comment: Yes. That will also give you the same result. Thanks Evan. My original quick answer was to address his syntax error. I added your solution to the answer with proper attribution. Thanks. I like you version.